# 2d graphics speed, old / new methods, etc

Tags: .net, windows, graphics

We've been experimenting with different graphics approaches for a new app, speed is important. We have an old app that uses GDI which is great - it can refresh 10,000 rounds with no apparent delay at all. For the new app, we would like to use C# or VB, with WPF, no problem I thought, Direct 2d will give us the same performance. But having tried many examples, we can't get anything anywhere near as fast. The same amount of drawing might take 300mS, it must be 10 or 100 times slower.

Is it really the case that if we want good graphics performance we have to stay with c++ / gdi, or are we missing something?

Is there a sample project in c# or vb which demonstrates the best graphics performance achievable?

Thanks